# Migration from NextJS to Remix.ru: route organisation by folders

Tags: remix.run

I am diving into Remix.run (v2) and cannot get how exactly co-located routes works (hope I called it right). I am nextjs guy so organising stuff by folders is my favorite thing. But here I cannot make it work. Ok, I got that only one-level nesting works for Remix, I am good with that (for instance, just keep API routes separate from others) but this files structure gives me 404 for `/api/test` route:

```
app
|-> routes
    |-> api
        |-> route.tsx
        |-> test.tsx
```

For test purpose each `tsx` file here declaring React component (just to ensure it works for specific segment of URL) like

```
export default function ApiPage = () => <div>api page</div>;
```

`/api` works ok and shows content from route.tsx

`/api/test.tsx` shows 404.

What I miss or what I did incorrectly?

Comment: [@remix-run/v1-route-convention](https://npmjs.com/package/@remix-run/v1-route-convention) - this package might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Among the files in the subpaths of Remix's `route` directory, the only file that creates a route is `route.tsx`.

In other words, the `route.tsx` file in Remix has the same role as the `page.tsx` file in Next.js.

Therefore, the following structure creates a page in the `/api` path.

```
app
|-> routes
    |-> api
        |-> route.tsx
```

The only file that creates a route is `route.tsx`, so any `test.tsx` file you add to the same path will not be a path.

One way you can create multiple subpaths is by using `.`.

```
app
|-> routes
    |-> api._index.tsx
    |-> api.test.tsx
```

Since `.` is changed to `/` when creating a path, the above structure creates the following two paths.

- `/api/`
- `/api/test/`

Another way is to use the [`remix-flat-routes`](https://github.com/kiliman/remix-flat-routes) library to create a folder as a path.

In this case you can create the path as you think, except adding `+` to the folder name that will be used as the path.

```
app
|-> routes
    |-> api+
        |-> index.tsx
        |-> test.tsx
```

The above structure produces the following two paths:

- `/api/`
- `/api/test/`